# dllexport avoiding template instanciation in header file

Tags: c++, templates, dllexport

I have a c++ class like the following that compiles fine until I try to export it from a dll.

MyClass.h:

```
class SomeClassNotDefinedHere;

class MyClass {
   protected:
   templated<SomeClassNotDefinedHere> m_member;     
}
```

If I export it using

```
 class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass
```

It fails to compile, trying to instanciate all inline members of `templated<SomeClassNotDefinedHere>`.

Is there a simple way to avoid this? I don't want to add SomeClassNotDefinedHere as a dependency of every library using MyClass.

Some of the templated code, this is a smart pointer like class. (tried to keep my example minimal, the real templated class is [osg::ref_ptr](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg/browser/OpenSceneGraph/trunk/include/osg/ref_ptr))

```
template<class T>
 class templated
{
    public:
        typedef T element_type;

        templated() : _ptr(0) {}
        templated(T* ptr) : _ptr(ptr) { if (_ptr) _ptr->ref(); }
        templated(const templated& rp) : _ptr(rp._ptr) { if (_ptr) _ptr->ref(); }
       private:
            T* _ptr;
}
```

Avoiding classes or large redesigns is something I would prefer to avoid, the code is already used on linux.

Comment: What is `templated`? Another class? Where is it defined and what does it look like? Please post compilable code.

Comment: `__declspec(dllexport)` on a class is a really bad idea to begin with.  I suggest making a C compatible API that accepts the object pointer as a parameter (just like the Win32 API), this is much more robust.

Comment: @Praetorian added some of the code and a link to the full class.

Comment: @BenVoigt since the classes are already in use I would prefer to avoid larger changes. (this is the first real problem I had with porting the library from linux to windows)